# Web pages generation (CMS like)

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

For learning purposes, I decided to find out how to does CMSs like Joomla generate web pages. The fact that there are no physical pages at all makes me feel uncomfortable. I mean you can not find `about.html` or `contacts.html` web pages on your hosting while using Joomla, all you have is a large number of PHP files which generate page you need from MySQL (I guess).

I would like to understand how does this work? What does Joomla do when someone goes to `http://example.com/about.html` for example? If there is no page `about.html` in my directory, how does Joomla generate the page I need when someone  goes through this link?

I can't formulate short question, due to lack of knowledge in this topic, that is why googling didn't help me a lot, so it would be great of someone could tell me where I should look or start from and some quick example.

I want at least to be able to create one page, which is generated by PHP when user goes to `example.com/topic.php` and know how it works.

**UPD:** Do i need this for the sake of SEO, or simple static pages are ok too?

Comment: It all starts in `.htaccess`. You will see a rule that makes access attempts to any non-existing files to call a determined PHP script instead, and it will then generate or route you to the desired content.

Comment: download joomla, read its source and manuals

Comment: Why are you uncomfortable about it? Most CMS's have a routing engine that directs requests to load the proper page. Page content is stored in a db so an infinite number of pages can be added.

Comment: It does not generate pages, it just gets identifier and contents from a database. like `example.com/1/title` the `1` is a database id,  so it fetch every content from db by that id. the extentions is just an apache trick. You'll get it soon :)

Comment: it generates pages (whatever they are) from the content in a db, rarely is the db content 100% the page.

Comment: If this gets close-voted, I'll vote for re-opening. It a newbie, but a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gave you an upvote for this:

> all you have infinity php files...

That's because Joomla's code is terrible. However, all content management systems have essentially the same problems to solve. The basic goal is to associate a given url with a desired "page" - which is the content/layout/style, etc. The admin panel let's you choose/create content and associate it to a given url. The content and settings are stored in the database. When you visit the site, you are actually directed to a single php file - `index.php`. That php file will pull in other php files that it needs to basically look at the current url, find the content and settings for that url, and display that content with those settings.

A large portion of your concern seems to be with routing. Check out my answer here for a basic example of routing (this should help you a lot): **[Htaccess and user accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594269/htaccess-and-user-accounts/21083766#21083766)**

Content management systems also usually allow you to separate the content of a page from it's design. This is an awesome thing. If you had 20 pages on your site and you decided to re-design the site, you don't have to touch the content at all. Consider this:

```
<article>
  <header>
    <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
    <time>{{article.date | date:'mediumDate'}}</time>
    <span>by <a href="{{article.authorHref}}">{{article.author}}</a></span>
    <p>From: <a href="{{article.categoryHref}}">{{article.category}}</a></p>
    <p>{{article.categoryDesc}}</p>
  </header>
  <section>{{article.content}}</section>
</article>
```

This is actual template markup from a CMS that I am creating. If I have 20 pages with articles, this one set of code will be repeated on all 20 pages. The handlebars `{{}}` are hooks for content to be pulled into from the database. So, if I want to change the article layout, I could simple open this template file and change it to something like:

```
<article>
  <section>{{article.content}}</section>
  <footer>
    <h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
    <time>{{article.date | date:'mediumDate'}}</time>
    <span>by <a href="{{article.authorHref}}">{{article.author}}</a></span>
    <p>From: <a href="{{article.categoryHref}}">{{article.category}}</a></p>
  </footer>
</article>
```

This would certainly be better than having to change the code in 20 files! A lot of things in a CMS are templated - the whole site as well as the individual content pieces (plugins) like a twitter feed, etc.

### Regarding SEO

SEO crawlers only see the page's source. At that point, there is no difference from static pages and CMS generated pages.

#### Urls

A great advantage of using a CMS is that it can enforce SEO principles. First, in order to get SEO urls, you have to implement some kind of routing so that your urls look like `site.com/about` rather than `site.com/about.html`. A good CMS will have this built-in.

#### Meta tags

While `<meta>` tags are less important now than they used to be, they can still be helpful. A CMS should automatically be generating these for you based on default settings with optional overrides for each page if you set them in the admin panel. You could argue that this ensures there is meta on every page and isn't subject to forgetfulness.

Comment: i just was asking about it! you've great intuition, thank you for SEO view point

Comment: @bla2eOD I saw your update =D

Comment: also, i guess that i can add some fields which take their data from DB, so it will be easier to update design or text as you mentioned, but still i'll have "real" html pages, right?

Comment: @bla2eOD Think about this: if you have a 5 page site and every page has the same header. footer, and sidebar, then you're going to want to make a file for each one of those. Then on each of the 5 pages, you'll just use `include "header.php";` etc. As I said, you also need to have a single php file to handle all requests just for the sake of fixing the urls (see my link about routing). That gives you something reasonably maintainable...but it's also getting closer to being a CMS =D. It's certainly not static pages.

Comment: i see what you mean, i was thinking about same thing, all i want to do is to make my pages smarter, so they can be edited by editing one file, may I call it semi-cms-like page? :P

Comment: @bla2eOD I would probably call it basic dynamic page generation. A CMS would have an admin panel since non-devs need to be able to use it, plus it's just nice.

Comment: I really don't think it's necessary to start with "it's because joomla code is terrible,"  joomla tends to use single responsibility  plus have a strong approach to making things overridable and makes things modular.  I think having having  a small number of overly complex and unreadable files is more terrivle. @bla2eOD  I'm not sure what your last page is, you edit joomla by editing with the built in edit functions, the UI for the editor is no different than what you'd get editing a single "page."

Comment: @Elin Joomla's code could be worse, but it's currently a very complex pile of spaghetti.  The creators aren't interested in improving the situation because they make their money selling books explaining their overly-complex code.

Comment: @Elin I didn't mean any offense. I appreciate the functionality of Joomla, of course! I just don't approve of the means that it achieves that functionality. That's partially due to its beginnings when php was a lot less powerful than it is today and the Joomla devs can't be blamed for that. Actually, I think they did an amazing job given the goals and the limitations they had to work with. I certainly don't mean any disrespect to the devs. Nonetheless, the code is a mess.

Answer (score 2):

I remember when I started using CMSes after making static pages for many years and the lack of html files was really strange to me as well. http://docs.joomla.org/Where_are_the_web_pages%3F

Joomla like most modern (aka "web 2.0") web applications separates presentation from content.
This is simplifying, of course, but ...

Content is stored in a database.
Presentation is managed by the template (either the default from Joomla or your replacement of the various parts).

Joomla is software that in response to a page request brings together your content and presentation and returns it, most commonly as HTML sent to a browser. 
Joomla helps you manage complex and dynamic page construction and reduces or eliminates the need to hand build pages but still lets you do as much hand building as you want, just in a different way.

PHP as a language was created with this idea in mind.

When Joomla makes a web page to put into your browser it does a number of things (simplifying again).
It loads the index.php of your template from the templates folder. This gives the page its basic structure.  If you look in that file you'll see your familiar `<html><head></head><body></body></html>` tags just like you would have in a static page. You'll also see css and javascript being included but not in the normal HTML way, rather in a way that is modified to make it more flexible. Same thing with  meta data, Joomla is going to put together metadata from different places (your site configuration, a specific article, etc) in a flexible way rather than you typing it separately in the file.

Once it gets to the `<body>` Joomla starts pulling in data and html layouts. It makes queries to different parts of the database to get say your article text, your list of links for the menu(s), to know find the most popular tags and so on, basically whatever data you want in your page.

It then gets what I call layouts which are basically the files that define the html for smaller parts of your page (such as the article text, the menu, the list of most popular tags).  These are a little spread out, but joomla first looks for them in your template's html folder (example templates/beez3/html) and if they aren't there it looks in the tmpl folders you'll see inside the views folders of the components and modules.  These days some shared elements of layouts are also found in the layouts folder that you'll find at the top level but these are called from the other layouts, never directly. 
So in the case of this page with an article, a menu, and a popular tags module it will get the layouts from

- /components/com_content/views/article/tmpl
- /modules/mod_menu/tmpl
- /modules/mod_tags_popular/tmpl

or any replacements for these you put in the html folder of your template.
Now Joomla basically takes the layouts and where they say to do it, it replaces PHP variables with the data from your database. 
So in popular tags we get code like this

```
<ul >
    <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
    <li><?php $route = new TagsHelperRoute; ?>
        <a href="<?php echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute($item->tag_id . '-' . $item->alias)); ?>">
            <?php echo htmlspecialchars($item->title); ?></a>
        <?php if ($display_count) : ?>
            <span class="tag-count badge badge-info"><?php echo $item->count; ?></span>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

So you see the `<ul></ul>,<li></li><span></span>` and `<a></a>` that you'd expect in html but we see that we're using PHP to automate things like getting the title text ($item->title) or the number of times a tag has been used ($item->count) or the url echo JRoute::_(TagsHelperRoute::getTagRoute($item->tag_id . '-' . $item->alias)); which is where Joomla is managing the routing and generating the SEF URL.
And that's why we use a CMS, to be able to automate all of those tasks so we can have thousands of pages all managed by just a few files.

Now, there are exceptions to and variations on the above. For example, you can get your data from a file or from a web service, you can return json instead of html, and so on, but that's the basic principle. Separate presentation from content, give the designer control over presentation but make it so she or he doesn't have to worry about content, make it so that the content creator doesn't have to worry about design, make it so the developer doesn't have to worry about either, make it simple enough that a webmaster who wears all three hats can still figure it out.

Now to generate the one page you want ... Joomla is never going to create a url with php at the end in the way you have it. It's always going to have either no extension or an extension you pick in global configuration usually .html or .htm.  So let's say instead you want topic.html.
 Go to the administrator, and make sure that you have turned on all of the SEF functions (and copied htaccess.txt to .htaccess or added it to your existing .htaccess). Then go to the article manager and create one article.  Then go to the menu manager and the main menu. Create a single item menu link  to the article with the  you created and make the alias "topic".    Now go to the front end of your site and refresh. Click on your new menu link.

---

Ok so the question then is what happens when Joomla sends a request in the form of a SEF URL. 
So first, let's pretend you are not using SEF urls, but instead have something like index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=7 ... in that case we can see what happens, we go to the com_content, article MVC and the model is going to use the id of 7 to make its query and what it finds in the article views/article/tmpl/default.php file to make the html. If I understand what you are asking.   So that's all pretty obvious, get the data from the posted url, run the query, return the html. 
So then as you rightly ask, what about when we don't have that? That's one of the hardest, most complex, and most argued about pieces of Joomla and many other systems. This is because when you have physical files they have clear names and they are clearly organized into hierarchical folders. Thus when you build a static page you completely control the url for a file by giving the file a name and then putting it in named folders.
There are different ways you can handle this problem in your system. For example if you have a finite number of pages/urls you can make a look up table or store a cached list in a file.
Or you can do what the current cms does which is to have a set up rules that you use to determine what that url is actually asking for. 
So, for example, you'll see that I told you to make a menu item with the alias "topic."  That is because the first thing Joomla does is check for menu items with an alias that exactly matches the url. The menu item table contains the matching complete dynamic url.  With that pattern of url, if it does not find an alias it's going to give you a 404. After that, when there is no menu item, finding matching valid urls becomes a lot more complicated, but in the end it's just a hierarchical set of rules for checking.

So the basic answer is, you do a simple or complex look up so you can get the data you need to let the mvc do its work. 
It's not simple in any way and it's one of the good arguments for using a solution with a track record for solving this problem.

Comment: that is amazingly clear answer, plused! But I think i didn't describe my idea clearly. I want to do something like joomla does, without using joomla. Yes, I do understand that i'll have a template which full of php code, like `<body><p><?php echo $content?></p></body>` or something like it, but I've troubles in understanding the moment when http://example.com/topic.html is being decoded by php (or something else) and used as POST (is it?) to make query to MySQLi and extract values i need. Where does it happen? How? I always thought that link its directory where document exist, but it isn't

Answer (score 1):

Joomla is a Content Management System, therefore to be able to manage content, it get's stored in a database rather than having separate html files. everything, whether it be content, menu items, extension names etc get stored in database tables.  With Joomla, you have 1 main index.php file which an application, well everything, gets pushed to. Joomla uses MVC (Model-View-Controller). Below are small summaries of what they are ([source](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/model-view-controller-MVC))

- A Model , which represents the underlying, logical structure of data in a software application and the high-level class associated with it. This object model does not contain any information about the user interface.
- A View , which is a collection of classes representing the elements
  in the user interface (all of the things the user can see and respond
  to on the screen, such as buttons, display boxes, and so forth)
- A Controller , which represents the classes connecting the model and the view, and is used to communicate between classes in the model and view.

The URL'S that you see, such as *http://example.com/about.html*, are SEF (Search Engine Friendly) and generated via the Joomla core. A standard URL may look somethign like this for an article:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=1
```

For more in-depth iformation about What Joomla is, have a read of this:

http://www.joomla.org/about-joomla.html

Hope this helps

Comment: * everything - except for images and other media; which get stored in the filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Most non-flatfile CMS systems utilize an MVC system of sorts, or at the very least, a templating system.

For example, Wordpress doesn't have specific pages for each post or page either, instead it keeps things in the DB which allows it's user easier management, and themes to easily access and change the data to fit the 'view' (or template in WP's case).

Most CMS platforms do this for a variety of reasons, all which relate to

- Ease of management. CMS platforms provide tools to easily edit content without having to access the filesystem and change the actual file.
- Ease of integration within enable UI changes.
- Ability to export the system and adapt to new environments. It's a lot easier uploading a Database export than a few hundred files and folders and hope to get it right.