# Need htaccess knowledge

Tags: php, .htaccess

I've put on htaccess on xamp (I've used it before)

but trying to change the following

```
index.php?admin&user&list
```

to

```
example.com/admin/user/list
```

I have a few other pages behind `/admin/`. Do I need to make 1 for every page?

Comment: [What's an alot?](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.nl/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Comment: Does that even matter? Still needs help

Comment: @dannii_destroyer .htaccess is not a good solution for routing. Check out this recent answer of mine http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594269/htaccess-and-user-accounts/21083766#21083766

Comment: Okey thanks mate will try it out :)

Comment: But im not using .php extensions does that still work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /index.php?%1/%2 [L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+index\.php\?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !&
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%{QUERY_STRING}? [L]
```

This makes it so when you request `http://example.com/index?abc&def&ghi`, the rules will internally route the request to `/abc/def/ghi`